# Meteor update template helper

Tags: javascript, meteor

If I have setup template helpers in meteor like so:

```
Template.leaderboard.helpers({
  players: function() {
    return Players.find({}, { sort: { score: -1, name: 1 } });
  });
```

How can I change the subscription after an event (say a click). For example, how can I reverse the sort after a click event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest possible way is to use the global `Session` object:

```
Session.setDefault('order', 1);

Template.leaderboard.helpers({
  players: function() {
    return Players.find({}, { sort: { score: Session.get('order'), name: 1 } });
  }
});
```

Now in your corresponding event hook you can toggle the ordering like this:

```
Template.leaderboard.events({
  'click': function () {
    Session.set('order', - Session.get('order'));
  }
});
```

However, if you would rather not use `Session`, you can also create a reactive state variable in your template instance namespace:

```
Template.leaderboard.created = function () {
  this.order = new ReactiveVar(1);
}
```

To access it from within a helper you can use:

```
Template.instance().order.get()
```

and in your event hook the template instance will be the second argument (efter event object):

```
Template.leaderboard.events({
  'click': function (e, t) {
    t.order.set( - t.order.get() );
  }
});
```

For the above code to work you will probably need to add `reactive-var` package to your meteor app.